# Increase speed of ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, activeadmin

In a rails application, ActiveAdmin is very slow. I realy need a performance boost and I need to keep filters.

I think the most consuming things are the filters and the drop down boxes. I see two options I can apply, cache and includes. So, I have two questions :

1. Is it possible to apply joins or includes when active admin find data? I need to apply scopes on filters and on associations.
2. Is it possible to apply cache on filter and on index?

This is an example for association. On a model, I have this :

```
class ProviderService < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :service
  belongs_to :provider_profile, foreign_key: :provider_profile_id

  def display_name
    [service.title, provider_profile.display_name].join(" - ")
  end
end
```

Each time a name is displayed, it do a query. It's very long.

A bonus question : Is there other solutions to boost perf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried many optimisations but it's not fast as I want. I think Activeadmin is good to do a admin part fast but it's better do use something else when it become more complexe. I tried [Smart Listing](https://github.com/Sology/smart_listing). It works well and it's more customizable.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved same issue by adding indexes into database. Try the same.